# remote debug without source code

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, remote-debugging, bytecode

I am connecting to a remote jvm and debug it. Some classes are generated in runtime and eclipse can not step through such classes.

How can I debug such classes without source code? I want at least to be able to step through bytecode of such classes.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I'll sugguest [Btrace](https://kenai.com/projects/btrace), BTrace can be used to dynamically trace a running Java program (similar to DTrace for OpenSolaris applications and OS). BTrace dynamically instruments the classes of the target application to inject tracing code ("bytecode tracing").

In one world, write a btrace script, specify target method with annotation, then you can trace the data and behavior of jvm from outside by Btrace.

This is quite useful to debug Java program in production environment and programs without source code.